# VSTO Get the fields in "group by" on Groupings in MS Project

Tags: vsto, ms-project

How will I get all fields in the "Group By" on a particular group in MS Project, using VSTO vb.net.

I tried this one:

```
Dim tg As MsProj.Group

Dim strGrp As String = ""

For Each tg In project.TaskGroups
    strGrp = strGrp & "/" & vbCrLf & tg.Name
Next

MsgBox(project.TaskGroups("Group 6").GroupCriteria.Count)

Dim qwe As MSProject.GroupCriteria

For Each qwe In project.TaskGroups("Group 6").GroupCriteria
    MsgBox(qwe)
Next
```

but i got error on the 2nd For loop

Thanks,
Gilbert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears there is an example for doing just this in the online documentation for the [GroupCriterion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/project-vba/articles/groupcriterion-object-project) object. Added here in case that link changes:

```
Dim GC As GroupCriterion 
Dim Fields As String 

For Each GC In ActiveProject.TaskGroups("Priority Keeping Outline Structure").GroupCriteria 
 If GC.Ascending Then 
   Fields = Fields & GC.Index & ". " & GC.FieldName & " is sorted in ascending order." & vbCrLf 
 Else 
   Fields = Fields & GC.Index & ". " & GC.FieldName & " is sorted in descending order." & vbCrLf 
 End If 
Next GC 

MsgBox Fields
```